# Como crear una carpeta desde la terminal y abrirla en visual studio

Tags: python

Como puedo crear y ejecutar carpetas desde la terminal y abrirla en visual estudio, estpy en un curso pero solo explica en Mac y yo soy e Windows.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que se muestra en la imagen no es Python, son comandos de la terminal y son los mismos comandos en Windows exceptuando Python3 que vendría siendo python. ¿Intentaste hacerlo? ¿Qué error te aparece?

Comment: `mkdir` (make dir, "hacer" directorio) y cd (change directory, cambiar directorio) son comandos que están disponibles en Windows también; todo lo que está escribiendo el profesor te va a funcionar también en Windows. 
Como extra, para abrir una carpeta desde la consola te ubicas primero en esa carpeta con el comando `cd` y después escribes y ejecutas `code .`, esto abrirá la carpeta donde estás en Code.